# BufferedImage why does this work?

Tags: java, jframe, render, bufferedimage

I'm going to post the code.  It's not too complicated or long.  I just don't understand why it works.

In the code below, image is rendered in the render method but it does not get updated in the game loop.  I can't figure out how image is getting updated.  The code runs and the output shows changing moving colors.  I see the tick method updating the `pixels[]` array but even outside the loop, pixels is set equal to data from image.  How is changing `pixels[]` changing image.  please help me understand this relationship.

*I'm sorry if I'm posting incorrectly.*  I did search but most people seem to have a problem where it doesn't work.  Mine works fine.  I just need to understand why.  Image is not getting updated in the tick method.  pixels is.  So why is image changing as if it's somehow connected to `pixels[]`???

**My Code Below :**

```
package com.channelsplace.game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.channelsplace.game.gfx.SpriteSheet;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private boolean running;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12*9;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    public static final String NAME = "Game";
    private JFrame frame;
    public int tickCount = 0;
/**********************************************************************
The next two lines are part of what I don't get.
below this you'll see a tick method that updates the pixels array
and a render method that renders image. but no overt flow of information 
from pixels to image.
**********************************************************************/ 
private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    private SpriteSheet spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("/sprite_sheet.png");

    public Game()
    {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        frame = new JFrame(NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000D/60D;
        int ticks = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0;
        boolean shouldRender = true;        
        while(running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;

            if (delta >= 1)             
            {
                ticks++;
                tick();
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (shouldRender)
            {
                frames++;
                render();
                shouldRender = false;
            }


            if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTimer>=1000)
            {
                lastTimer += 1000;
                System.out.println(frames+" , "+ticks);
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    public void tick()
    {
        tickCount++;
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        {
            pixels[i] = i + tickCount;
        }
    }

    public void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Game().start();

    }
}

//thanks for reading
```

Comment: Short answer (since this would be complicated to answer even in a long one), _[`BufferImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) relies on the data fetching and setting methods of Raster_, since you get a `WritableRaster` and then get the array, you basically old the `Image` data directly in you array. But I can't say if this is a good solution or not. I would have used the [`WritableRaster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) but it might be more expensive that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it does not get updated in the game loop.

The `image` **DOES** get updated in the game loop:

```
public void tick()
{
    tickCount++;
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
    {
        // where the image gets updated
        // pixels[i] = i + tickCount; // <-- it does exactly the same as the alternative below
        image.setRBG(i/WIDTH, i%WIDTH, i + tickCount);
    }
}
```

> Sounds obvious but pixels[] is an int[] as declared and not part of image.

I see where the confusion lies.

What is an image? An image is just a number of pixels, stored in the int array `pixels[]`.

Let's say you create a `BufferedImage` of 20x30 size, internally it creates an int array of size 20*30, or 600. Each int in the array represent 1 pixel, in RGB colour model, i.e., each int value is a combination of 3 components R(Red)/G(Green)/B(Blue). Each component takes 8 bits of the int (32 bits). The remaining 8 bits can be used for Alpha channel (transparency) if supported.

(If you look at the source code of `BufferedImage`, it does not create the int array by itself, it uses `RasterWriter`, which uses `DataBuffer`, this is implementation details, I will leave it out to avoid more confusion.)

The `BufferedImage` provides a number of methods for the access (i.e., read/write) to the values in the array.

In `tick()` you write directly to the array `pixels[]`, you can also call the method `setRGB(x, y, rgb)` to write to the array, either way, you're modifying the same array, the so-called "image".

In `render()`, it paints the "image", i.e., it reads the values from the array contained in the image, and draw the pixels on the screen.

Hope this is a bit clearer.

Comment: A little clarification please.  I understand you're saying I have direct access to the array pixels[].  I can see that.  No problem.  *** how is it that changing pixels[] changes image?***  I don't see a relationship being formed where changing values of individual elements in pixels[] should impact image.  I see pixels[] being assigned values based on image.  Sounds obvious but pixels[] is an int[] as declared and not part of image.  Thanks for your time in trying to explain this to me.

Comment: @ChannelSanderson Seems that your confusion is with how an image is represented in computer. Just added some more explanation. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Thank you Kevin.  Your explanation finally broke through.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.
I figured out finally that when pixels[] is created, it's pointed at the data of image.  I had it in my head that it was a separate int[] and where pixels[] was created, the data was being copied to it with the '='.  But that's not the case.  It's pointing at the data in image. It's not a deep copy.  pixels and the image data share the same memory address.
Thank you for your patience.
Channel